# What are the last 2 digits of $31^{41}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

By using a slick trick, I found that the last two digits were $31.$ However, I want to verify this using Fermat's little theorem or some alternate. How would I apply Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: What was the slick trick you used? This might reduce duplication of effort. Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: @robjohn I don't even have a name for it. But you I do have a link here: <https://gmatclub.com/forum/shortcut-to-find-tens-digit-last-two-digit-of-a-number-188697.html>

Comment: It is best if you can retell what it says there in your question. It is easier on the reader and better in case a link goes stale. For instance, when I click on your link, it tells me that the page cannot be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$
a^{\varphi(100)}=1
$$
where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. 
$$
\varphi(100)=\varphi(2^2)\varphi(5^2)=2(20)=40
$$
since it is multiplicative on relatively prime numbers. Note also that 
$$
\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1)
$$
it is now easy to conclude.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Answer (score 8):

Since $\phi(100) = 40$ we have by Euler theorem $$31^{40}\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$$

So the answer is $31$.

Answer (score 2):

John Watson's approach is what I would go with, but to add an alternative, we can raise $31^{41}\pmod{100}$ using the [Square and Multiply Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). First, note that $41=101001_{\text{two}}$
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|rl}
n&\text{base two}&31^n\pmod{100}\\
0&0&1\\
1&1&31&\text{multiply}\\
2&10&61&\text{square}\\
4&100&21&\text{square}\\
5&101&51&\text{multiply}\\
10&1010&1&\text{square}\\
20&10100&1&\text{square}\\
40&101000&1&\text{square}\\
41&101001&31&\text{multiply}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You changed the problem on me after I answered. So:

Two find the last two digits, just work in $\mathbb Z\bmod100.$
\begin{align}
33^1 & \equiv 31 \\
31^2 & \equiv 31\times 31 \equiv 61 \\
31^3 & \equiv 31\times61 \equiv 91 \\
31^4 & \equiv 31\times91 \equiv 21 \\
31^5 & \equiv 31\times21 \equiv 51 \\
31^6 & \equiv 31\times51 \equiv 81 \\
31^7 & \equiv 31\times81 \equiv 11 \\
31^8 & \equiv 31\times11 \equiv 41 \\
31^9 & \equiv 31\times41 \equiv 71 \\
31^{10} & \equiv 31\times71 \equiv 1
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
31^{41} = 31^{10}\times31^{10}\times31^{10}\times31^{10}\times31^1 \equiv 1\times1\times1\times1\times31 \equiv 31.
$$

<s>Two find the last two digits, just work in $\require{cancel}\xcancel{\mathbb Z\bmod100.}$
$$
\xcancel{
\begin{align}
32^1 & \equiv 32 \\
32^2 & \equiv 32\times 32 \equiv 24 \\
32^3 & \equiv 32\times24 \equiv 68 \\
32^4 & \equiv 32\times68 \equiv 76 \\
32^5 & \equiv 32\times76 \equiv 32
\end{align}}
$$
After five steps you're back to $32.$</s>

Every time you go four steps beyond where you had $32,$ you have $32$ again. So $41 = 1 + (1\times4)$ so you go through that cycle $10$ times, getting back to $32.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(1+10n)^m\equiv1+\binom m1(10n)^1\pmod{100}$$

Now, $41\cdot3\equiv3\pmod{10}$

$\implies41\cdot30\equiv30\pmod{100}$

Answer (score 0):

We begin by stating two general/abstract/elementary statements without proof.

Proposition 1; The set of all invertible elements in a monoid forms a group under its binary operation.

If $\mathcal M$ is a monoid we denote by $\mathcal M_G$ this group.

Proposition 2: Let $\mathcal M$ be a finite monoid and let  $\mathcal K \subset \mathcal M_G$ be closed under the binary operation. Then $\mathcal K$ is a group.

---

Define

$$ \mathcal K = \{ a \in (\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z})^\times \mid a = [d10 + 1] \text{ with } 0 \le d \le 9\}$$

So $\mathcal K$ is a group and $|\mathcal K| = 10$. By Lagrange's theorem, The order of the cyclic group generated by $[31]$ must divide $10$. Every divisor of $10$ divides $40$ and we conclude that

$$ 31^{41} \equiv 31 \pmod{100}$$